# Window dimming in WinForms .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, screen, system.drawing

Many times I've seen an effect in Adobe Flash that gradually reduces visibility of the background window, for example when you preview a video or image (in Lightbox). It would be great to have such effect in WinForms. 
After searching the web for relevant solution, I've found a program that dims the entire screen. Obviously, this works differently, a semi-transparent bar is stretched to the screen area. I would like to find the same thing for the application window (so when we display a dialog, main form will appear slightly darker).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just as the original approach, this requires an overlay.  All you have to do is make it smaller, giving it the Size and Location of the main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a very similar question before, see:

[WinForm Control with Opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106449/winform-control-with-opacity/6107137#6107137)

The Shroud() and Unshroud() methods dim and undim the form.

You can modify that to do what you want (using a timer; instead of dimming the bitmap (see example code) you can do the dimming on Paint() and make it time-dependent.

Send me a comment if you need a code sample, I can work one out for you.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but looks like the solution I'm looking for.